ContentLength is null on Production, but populated in Development .NET 8 / C#
Created a very simple middleware in (using C# and .NET 8) to track users, the endpoints they are connecting to, the size of the request and the size of the response. This works perfectly on my machine when I run dotnet run, but when this is uploaded to the server, which is running Windows 2022 using IIS, the response length is always NULL.
Here is the middleware code:
/// <summary>
/// Configure our httpRequest to be buffered so we can read it multiple times ourselves
/// </summary>
public class UserTrackingMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public UserTrackingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        //  get host from the request and check if it's in the enumeration of allowed hosts
        var url = context.Request.GetDisplayUrl();
        var querystring = context.Request.QueryString.ToString();
        var endpoint = context.GetEndpoint();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(querystring))
        {
            url = url.Replace(querystring, string.Empty);
            querystring = querystring.Substring(1);
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
        {
            var scope = context.RequestServices.CreateScope();
            var currentUser = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ICurrentUser>();
            var user = await currentUser.GetAsync();

            if (currentUser.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                var watch = new Stopwatch();
                watch.Start();

                var dataContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IDataContext>();

                // userAgent
                var userAgent = "unavailable";

                if (context.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("User-Agent", out var parsedUserAgent))
                    userAgent = parsedUserAgent.ToString();

                // contentLength
                long? requestLength = null;

                if (headerKeys.Contains("Content-Length", StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    requestLength = long.Parse(context.Request.Headers["Content-Length"].ToString());

                // headers
                var httpHeaders = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                foreach (var header in headerKeys.OrderBy(e => e))
                    httpHeaders.Add(header, context.Request.Headers[header]);

                var log = new UserTracking
                {
                    UserId = user.Id,
                    Url = url,
                    QueryString = querystring,
                    RequestLength = requestLength,
                    UserAgent = userAgent,
                    Method = context.Request.Method.ToLower(),
                    Headers = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(httpHeaders)
                };

                dataContext.SetAdded(log);

                try
                {
                    await dataContext.SaveChangesAsync(context.RequestAborted);

                    // To add Headers AFTER everything you need to do this
                    context.Response.OnStarting(async () =>
                    {
                        watch.Stop();

                        var sqlBuilder = new SqlBuilder("UPDATE UserTracking SET ElapsedMilliseconds = {0}, ResponseLength = {1} WHERE Id = {2}", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds, context.Response.ContentLength, log.Id);
                        await dataContext.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync(sqlBuilder);
                    });
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    // an error occurred here
                }
            }
        }

        await _next(context);
    }
}

On my local machine, the SQL results look like this:

But on the server, you can see responseLength is NULL:

My local launchSettings.json looks like this:
"https": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
}

I have read that the response contentLength is NULL because the response is not buffered and you need to put it in a memory stream to get the response length, but why does it work on development but not on the server?
The middleware is added via the Program.cs as you can see here:
// must be done before all other middleware, expect developer exception page
app.UseHsts(options =>
{
    options.MaxAge(120, 0, 1, 0);
    options.AllResponses();
    options.IncludeSubdomains();
});

// middleware
app.UseGlobalExceptionHandler();
app.UseOperationCancelledExceptionHandler();
app.UseResponseCaching();
app.UseResponseCompression();

// Content Security Policy (CSP)
app.UseSecurityPolicy();
app.UseCsp(options =>
{
    ...
});

// swagger
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
{
    ...
});

// app
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"wwwroot", "app")),

    // accessing wwwroot inside folder contents
    RequestPath = new PathString(""),

    // add cache headers
    OnPrepareResponse = (context) =>
    {
        var headers = context.Context.Response.GetTypedHeaders();
        headers.CacheControl = new CacheControlHeaderValue()
        {
            Public = false,
            Private = true,
            MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromHours(24)
        };

        // these are also in the securityPolicyMiddleware
        headers.Set("Permissions-Policy", "accelerometer=(), gyroscope=(), magnetometer=(), microphone=(), payment=(), usb=()");
        headers.Set("Referrer-Policy", "strict-origin-when-cross-origin");
        headers.Set("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff");
        headers.Set("X-Frame-Options", "DENY");
        headers.Set("X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies", "none");
    }
});

// Enable middleware to serve generated Swagger as a JSON endpoint
app.UseSwagger(options =>
{
    ...
});

// Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui assets (HTML, JS, CSS etc.)
app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
{
    ...
});

// routing
app.UseRouting();

// CORS - Configuring is with MvcExtensions
app.UseCors();

// comment this out and you get an error saying 
// InvalidOperationException: No authentication handler is configured to handle the scheme: Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.External
app.UseAuthentication();

// for authorization headers
app.UseAuthorization();

// antiforgery
app.UseAntiforgery();

// user tracking  <!--  HERE
app.UseUserTracking();


Based on the info you gave us, you use Windows 2022 with IIS. This version of IIS works with HTTP/2 (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-10/http2-on-iis).

The Content-Length header is not sent because HTTP/2 and HTTP/3
framing are based on the END_STREAM flag.
HTTP/2/3, being binary protocols with frames, can just encode this
information in the last frame for that request/response. It is a
HEADERS or DATA frame having the END_STREAM flag set to true that
determines if there is request/response content, and if so, what frame
carries the last content bytes.
In summary, the Content-Length header is not necessary in HTTP/2 and
HTTP/3 because they have a different framing than HTTP/1.1.

This is the original answer that explains why is not set: Why is content-length header not sent over HTTP/3?
